# Searching for a specific font size for titles

Tags: fontsize

I must write an article with a specific size for titles: 14 pt and 12pt for the text. How could I do that? This is my MWE :

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openany]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\title{}
\author{}


\begin{document}
\maketitle


\pagestyle{headings}

\section{A title}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

All sections and the size of the title are 14 pt. The lipsum text is 12pt.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openany]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\LARGE}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\LARGE}{\LARGE}{}{}
\makeatother

\title{\textbf{14 A title}}
\author{xxhh}



\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagestyle{headings}
\section{A title}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: By "title", I meant the title of the section named "A title". Is it the same size, 14 pt?

Comment: @domi Now I hope "yes" :-).

Comment: why not use this one: \sectionfont{\Large}?

Comment: @domi Why there is a different of the size of the section and the title.